# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in line 13

Tags: php, syntax-error

i keeping getting tht error "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in line 13** " for my code ...its as below

```
<?php

    $all= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'books', 'numberposts' => -1,));

    foreach ( $all as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

        if (!empty($post))
        {
        $postid=$post->ID;
        echo $postid;
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: You open `foreach` but don't close it :( Much sad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to end your `foreach`

```
<?php

$all= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'books', 'numberposts' => -1,));

foreach ( $all as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

    if (!empty($post))
    {
    $postid=$post->ID;
    echo $postid;
    }
 endforeach;
?>
```